# Which Google API to use for Domain users

Tags: c#, google-api

Here is the context :
I am the admin of a Google Domain for my enterprise. I need to load every user and manage their access rights for Google Drives directories.

I already use the Google Drive API to upload file. Can it manage access rights also ? Which API can I use to list users ?

Thanks for your help and sorry if this is a dumb question !

Answer (score 0):

I think that the Google Domain API is this one [Google+ Platform - APIs for Google Apps](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/). No its not the same as the Google Drive API that you are using.